# Can't get flutter_secure_storage to work on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, flutter, archlinux, flutter-secure-storage

I am on Arch Linux:

```
Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Arch Linux 6.4.8-arch1-1
```

and I am trying to use [flutter secure storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) but I keep getting this error:

```
** (home_services_customer:14756): WARNING **: 14:44:06.788: libsecret_error: o\xa1\x96\xd4\xfdU
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid UTF-8 byte (at offset 0)
#0      _Utf8Decoder.convertSingle (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1747:7)
#1      Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:351:42)
#2      StandardMessageCodec.readValueOfType (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:503:29)
#3      StandardMessageCodec.readValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:478:12)
#4      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:47)
#5      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      StorageApi.getAccessToken (package:home_services_customer/api/storage.dart:11:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AuthController.checkAuth (package:home_services_customer/controllers/auth.dart:27:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

In the docs they say:

> You need `libsecret-1-dev` and `libjsoncpp-dev` on your machine to build the project, and `libsecret-1-0` and `libjsoncpp1` to run the application (add it as a dependency after packaging your app).

So I checked and I found that I have these packages already installed:

```
core/libsecret 0.20.5-2 [installed]
    Library for storing and retrieving passwords and other secrets

core/json-c 0.16-1 [installed]
    A JSON implementation in C

extra/json-glib 1.6.6-2 [installed]
    JSON library built on GLib

extra/jsoncpp 1.9.5-2 [installed]
    C++ library for interacting with JSON
```

Here is the main function:

```dart
main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Locales.init(['ar', 'en']);

  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: ScreenUtilInit(
        builder: (context, child) => LocaleBuilder(
          builder: (locale) {
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              title: 'Flutter Demo',
              localizationsDelegates: Locales.delegates,
              supportedLocales: Locales.supportedLocales,
              locale: locale,
              theme: appThemeData(context),
              home: const InitialScreen(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

and here is where I use the package:

```dart
class StorageApi {
  final FlutterSecureStorage _storage;
  static const String keyAccessToken = 'access_token';
  static const String keyRefreshToken = 'access_token';

  StorageApi(this._storage);

  Future<String?> getAccessToken() async {
    final token = await _storage.read(key: keyAccessToken); // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    return token;
  }

  Future<String?> getRefreshToken() async {
    return await _storage.read(key: keyRefreshToken);
  }

  Future<void> saveTokens({
    String? accessToken,
    String? refreshToken,
  }) async {
    if (accessToken !=  null) {
      await _storage.write(key: keyAccessToken, value: accessToken);
    }
    if (refreshToken != null) {
      await _storage.write(key: keyRefreshToken, value: refreshToken);
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I didn't have my default keyring unlocked for some reason, it worked as soon as I unlocked it using [Seahorse](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/seahorse/).